# How to turn off caching of your website in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching

I'm trying to prevent caching of confidential files on the browser(chrome), so every time a request is made, fetch the files from the server, instead of viewing from cache. I added the following html meta tags, to instruct the chrome browser to not cache, but with no luck.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

upon inspecting the network traffic,  cache-control is set to max-age=0 on request. and private on response.

I have this working for IE though.

Comment: meta http-equiv is a joke, use real HTTP instead

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would rather do this in the .htacces file, based on filetype (or any other pattern), example:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
 </FilesMatch>

 <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Replace my simple example with a pattern of your choice. Also for reference here is more detail information on this topic: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html